# Why does a move constructor need to be declared noexcept for std::vector to use it?

Tags: c++, move, stdvector, copy-constructor, move-constructor

Consider the following code:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(){std::cout << "Default constructor" << std::endl;} 

    Foo(const Foo&) {std::cout << "Copy constructor" << std::endl;}
    Foo& operator =(const Foo& f)
    {
        std::cout << "Copy constructor" << std::endl;
        return *this;
    }

    Foo(const Foo&&) {std::cout << "Move constructor" << std::endl;}
    Foo& operator =(const Foo&& f)
    {
        std::cout << "Move constructor" << std::endl;
        return *this;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Foo> vec{Foo(), Foo()};
    std::cout << "---" << std::endl;
    vec.push_back(Foo());
}
```

The expected output for this would be:

```
Default constructor
Default constructor
Copy constructor
Copy constructor
---
Default constructor
Move constructor
Move constructor
Move constructor
```

However, the actual output the above code generates is this:

```
Default constructor
Default constructor
Copy constructor
Copy constructor
---
Default constructor
Move constructor
Copy constructor
Copy constructor
```

The vector is using the copy constructor when resizing. But if I declare the move constructor as `noexcept`, it will be used correctly by std::vector.

```
Foo(const Foo&&) noexcept { ... }
```

```
Default constructor
Default constructor
Copy constructor
Copy constructor
---
Default constructor
Move constructor
Move constructor
Move constructor
```

Why is this?

Comment: On a resize the vector would move all objects to the new location. If one of them throws an exception, the original vector must be preserved, which is not possible if other objects are already moved away. Therefore, it can only use the move constructor if it cannot throw.

Comment: Also, you cannot move const object `Foo(const Foo&&)` is wrong.

Comment: @rafix07 True. Forgot about that